# Как запретить фокусировку на элементах в определённом div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Я запретил взаимодействие с элементами через свойство pointer-events: none, но позже заметил, что через tab к ним можно получить доступ.

Я не могу на каждый элемент установить tab-index=-1, это слишком трудно в моём случае и долго по времени.

Есть ли способ как-то перехватить нажатие tab, чтобы не было возможности сфокусироваться на любом из детей div?

Пробовал делать e.preventDefault() (вешал событие onKeyDown на div), но это ничего не дало.

Comment: Хорошо бы привести пример.

Answer (score 0):

Если руками устанавливать значения трудно и долго - переложите работу на javascript

```js
let elem = document.getElementById('one')

for(let n=0;n<10;n++){
  let newElem = document.createElement('input')
  newElem.textContent = n
  newElem.setAttribute('tabindex', -1)
  elem.after(newElem)
}
```

```css
#parent>*{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <input type="text" placeholder="раз" id="one">
  <input id="two" placeholder="два" >
</div>
```